# Conditionally eliminating one of two colliding bodies

Tags: java, collision

I like to explicit return function even for void functions to reduce the use of if-elses, like this code snippet:

```
private void processContactBetweenPlayers(Contact contact) {
    final Body bodyA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    final Body bodyB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    if (!isPlayer(bodyA) || !isPlayer(bodyB)) {
        return;
    }
    final float vx_a = Math.abs(bodyA.getLinearVelocity().x);
    final float vx_b = Math.abs(bodyB.getLinearVelocity().x);
    final float vy_a = Math.abs(bodyA.getLinearVelocity().y);
    final float vy_b = Math.abs(bodyB.getLinearVelocity().y);
    final float a_power = vx_a + vy_a;
    final float b_power = vx_b + vy_b;
    if ((a_power > b_power)) {
        if (save(bodyB)) return;
        markForDestroy(bodyB);
    } else {
        if (save(bodyA)) return;
        markForDestroy(bodyA);
    }
}
```

The function returns if both bodies are not players. But doing maybe this practice reduces the code readability. What do you think?

Comment: you could also consider throwing an IllegalArgumentException, if you want to make it clear that you only want to process contacts between 2 players.

Comment: I think this is not case to throw exception, since I have a lot of objects in my game (represented by Body) and a lot times a contact will not be between players object. But somehow you're right since the method name make us think it's an exception when Contact fixtures are not both players. I think I have to make the veriifcation out his method or change the name to processContact or something like.

Comment: The method name explicitely says the contact is between players, which would tend to indicate that it expects the input to be filtered before.

Comment: Could you tell us what `save(bodyB)` does, and what its return value means?

Comment: actually this code is only for prototype purposes, probably save method will be removed. but it means something like: there is a last chance to body don't be destroyed, if 'save' returns true.  Like: it returns true if a random number are greater than 0.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IMHO this is perfectly fine.

```
if (!isPlayer(bodyA) || !isPlayer(bodyB)) {
    return;
}
```

This is an early return, saving you one indentation level.

```
    if (save(bodyB)) return;
    markForDestroy(bodyB);
```

This is not as good. Here, I'd go for

```
    if (!save(bodyB)) markForDestroy(bodyB);
```

Note that braces should be used around single statements as well, i.e.,

```
    if (!save(bodyB)) {
        markForDestroy(bodyB);
    }
```

> But doing maybe this practice reduces the code readability.

No, used wisely it helps readability. When reading top down, you know that both bodies are players. In an if-block you know this too, but the indentation may get excessive. Moreover, using the early return makes clear that only players are dealt with.

---

As stated in the comments, `processContact` would be a much better name. A method called `processContactBetweenPlayers` could be extracted (not needed now as it's rather short). Such a method should use something like

```
checkArgument(isPlayer(bodyA) && isPlayer(bodyB));
```

in case it's `public`, otherwise I'd recommend

```
assert isPlayer(bodyA) && isPlayer(bodyB);
```

While asserts are often frowned upon, this is exactly what they're good for.

Answer (score 6):

The first early return is fine.

```
if (!isPlayer(bodyA) || !isPlayer(bodyB)) {
    return;
}
```

This immediately tells the programmer that both bodies must be players.

The later ones less so, You can invert the condition and put the markForDestroy call in the then clause.

```
if (!save(bodyB)) 
    markForDestroy(bodyB);
```

I would add some blank lines to break up the function a bit though:

```
private void processContactBetweenPlayers(final Contact contact) {
    final Body bodyA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    final Body bodyB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    if (!isPlayer(bodyA) || !isPlayer(bodyB)) {
        return;
    }

    final float vx_a = Math.abs(bodyA.getLinearVelocity().x);
    final float vx_b = Math.abs(bodyB.getLinearVelocity().x);
    final float vy_a = Math.abs(bodyA.getLinearVelocity().y);
    final float vy_b = Math.abs(bodyB.getLinearVelocity().y);

    final float a_power = vx_a + vy_a;
    final float b_power = vx_b + vy_b;

    if ((a_power > b_power)) {
        if (!save(bodyB)) 
            markForDestroy(bodyB);
    } else {
        if (!save(bodyA))
            markForDestroy(bodyA);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it odd that the "power" is defined as the sum of the horizontal and vertical components of the velocity.  I would expect it to be based on the speed, which is \$v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}\$.  More specifically, I'd expect to compare the kinetic energies of the bodies, \$\frac{1}{2} mv^2\$.

Therefore, I would expect to see

```
if ((vx_a * vx_a + vy_a + vy_a) > (vx_b * vx_b + vy_b + vy_b)) {
    …
} else {
    …
}
```

If you are instead modelling physics in some bizarro world where movement along the horizontal and vertical axes is considered less powerful than diagonal movement, then there should be an explanatory comment in the code.

Comment: It's not so important. I doing this simple calcule to see my bodies being destroyed for now, but that code will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would simply this:

First, I would create a reduced method for getting "body" in fixture as such:

```
contact.getBody("A");
```

Underneath the covers this could be

```
contact.getFixtureA().getBody()
```

But by doing it this way you

1. Shorten the code
2. Create a type of factory method for these "fixtures". This may not be appropriate for your case but with no other context that is what I would do

And, what's with all the

> final

Craziness? You only need to do this if you want to assure yourself (or the compiler) that it won't be reassigned. This is hyper defensive and, in 15 years of writing code I have never found it to be a necessity.

Frankly, 'final' in this case is repetitive and distracting. Unless you have a need for it (which, from this code, you don't) then ditch it.

this:

```
    if (!isPlayer(bodyA) || !isPlayer(bodyB)) {
        return;
    }
```

is good, but this:

```
    if (!isPlayer(bodyA) || !isPlayer(bodyB)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both bodies must be players!");
    }
```

Is way better! Think about it: In the previous case, you 'return' and terminate the function. But, in this condition you have no idea if the job was done or not and if not, why not. This is pre-condition checking and an ideal case for it

```
    final float vx_a = Math.abs(bodyA.getLinearVelocity().x);
    final float vx_b = Math.abs(bodyB.getLinearVelocity().x);
```

Your variable names mean zilch to me. You HAVE to give them a better name. Also, create them up in groups of 2.

This code here is also problematic.

```
        if (save(bodyB)) return;
        markForDestroy(bodyB);
```

The return statements are pointless here. You could just do:

```
        if (!save(bodyB)) 
            markForDestroy(bodyB);
```

And now, a line is gone and your code flows naturally and doesn't abruptly exit the function.

Finally, this thing where you put your

```
return
```

on the same line is both cluttering and unnatural; They are sequential instructions to the CPU:

```
mv e248484 EAX
cmp 0
JMP ...
POPS
```

Ok, yes that is 80686 assembly but you get the point. It's a branch and function return.

All, of course, my .02 USD

Comment: I disagree with the stringly typed function. Instead if you still want only one function to get either then it should be an int.

Comment: @ratchetfreak huh?

Comment: I'm talking about `contact.getBody("A")` no need for the magic string, use index of enum instead.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I don't know what 'index of enum' you're referring to. Did I miss some code? This follows the factory pattern and allows the body to be polymorphic. If there is an enum to be used, then, ok.

Comment: typo, I meant "index or enum"

Comment: @ratchetfreak I could put getBodyA and getBodyB directly in Contact, but I don't like this type of shortcut so much. Besides, Contact, Fixture and Body are not mine. They belongs the game engine API. That finals are putted by Intellij. I will change the code completation config to avoid them. The exception throws you suggest are ok, but I changed the code in my own answer below and put verification off the method.

Comment: Lol, about  variable names "final float vx_a" sorry it's a rapid prototype code to see things happening, but I will change. Actually my original intention with this question was to ask only about the "return ;"  interrupting function, I went on the momentum and change other things.

Answer (score 2):

`processContactBetweenPlayers` is not a great name.
A good name should describe what the method does,
so the readers can make a good guess without studying the implementation.
"process" is a wishy-washy term that doesn't mean anything.

This method also knows too much about the internal workings of a `Contact` object.
By the [law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter),
it would be good to avoid making chained references to `contact.getFixtureA().getBody()`.
It would be better to pass two instances of `Body` to this method.
Then the method could be renamed to:

```
private void collideBodies(Body bodyA, Body bodyB) { ... }
```

---

Still about naming,
it's a common practice to prefix method names that return a `boolean` value with `is` or `has`. Judging by your posted revised version,
it would seem that `isSaved` would be a better name than `save`.

---

Since the calculation logic of the "power" is the same for both `bodyA` and `bodyB` and you have it repeated twice,
it would be good to move this to a helper method.
That would have the additional positive effect of hiding from this method the logic of calculating power,
making it more cohesive,
focusing on handling the collision,
and not doing additional calculations.

---

In this condition you have some redundant parentheses:

> ```
>     if ((a_power > b_power)) {
> ```

Comment: I aggree 'process' is not good name, but there are other types of colisions between other types of bodies that will be treated.

Comment: Of you had included those in your post, this would have been a different answer ;-)

Answer (score -2):

After answers and comments I refactoring my code spliting the code in several methods.

```
private void processContact(Contact contact) {
    final Body bodyA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    final Body bodyB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    if (areBothPlayers(bodyA, bodyB)) {
        processContactBetweenPlayers(contact, bodyA, bodyB);
    }
    // others contacts processing.
}

private void processContactBetweenPlayers(Contact contact, Body playerBodyA,     Body playerBodyB) {
    final float vx_a = Math.abs(playerBodyA.getLinearVelocity().x);
    final float vx_b = Math.abs(playerBodyB.getLinearVelocity().x);
    final float vy_a = Math.abs(playerBodyA.getLinearVelocity().y);
    final float vy_b = Math.abs(playerBodyB.getLinearVelocity().y);

    final float a_power = vx_a + vy_a;
    final float b_power = vx_b + vy_b;

    if (a_power > b_power) {
        if (!saved(playerBodyA)) {
            destroyIfNotSaved(playerBodyA);
        }
    } else {
        if (!saved(playerBodyB)) {
            destroyIfNotSaved(playerBodyB);
        }
    }
}

public void destroyIfNotSaved(Body playerBody) {
    if (!saved(playerBody)) {
        markForDestroy(playerBody);
    }
}

private boolean areBothPlayers(Body bodyA, Body bodyB) {
    return isPlayer(bodyA) && isPlayer(bodyB);
}
```

Comment: Using so many small methods, it's fine, but now it really cries for a method `float power(playerBody)`. +++ You forgot to use `destroyIfNotSaved`.

Comment: ChristianBongiorno and maaartinus, I see, I will correct the code.